Trying to create Azure Alerts using Terraform Modules
I’m trying to create some alerts in Terraform for App Gateways, so I can re-use them across several tenants/subs as/when I want to set them up. My idea is once created, is to create alerts for different types of resource and then put them on GitHub for anyone else to re-use.
At the moment - my criteria for the alerts looks something like this:

I’m trying to create this using modules (Because I’ve never done it before properly, so why not give it a try) but I’m having issues with the Criteria block. My idea is that I add each alert criteria into the terraform.tfvars file, and specify what alert group is notified in the main.tf (ie some alerts just need adding into the ITSM/Project Mailbox, others just an On-Call team, some maybe to all 3).
My files looks like this:
Main.tf
provider “azurerm” {
features {}
subscription_id = var.tfvars.subscription_id
tenant_id = var.tfvars.tenant_id
skip_provider_registration = true
}

module “action_groups” {
source = “./modules/action-groups”
for_each = var.region.action_groups
action_groups = each.value
resource_group_name = var.region.resource_group_name
}

module “monitor_activity_log_alerts” {
source = “./modules/azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert”
for_each = var.region.monitor_activity_log_alerts_prd
monitor_activity_log_alerts = each.value
action_group_ids = module.action_groups.action_group_id
}

Terraform.tfvars:
tfvars = {

init
subscription_id = “<Subscription_ID>” #Add in new Sub Names/ID’s in tenant as time goes on
tenant_id = “<Tenant_ID>”
}

region = {

resource_group_name = “appgw”
#resource_group_names = “monitoring”
location = “uksouth”

action_groups = {
  “1” = {
      name = “Action-Group-ITSM-Alerts”,
      short_name = “AG-ITSM”,
      email_receiver = {
        1 = {
          email_address = “ITSMEmail@company.com”
          name = “ITSM-Support-Alerts”
          use_common_alert_schema = false
          },
        2 = {
          email_address = “ProjectMailbox@company.com”
          name = “projmailbox_-EmailAction-”
          use_common_alert_schema = false
          }
         }
         arm_role_receiver = {}
         },
   “2” = {
       name = “Action-Group-OnCall-Aware”,
       short_name = “AG-OnCall”,
       email_receiver = {
         1 = {
         email_address = “OnCallTeam@company.com”
         name = “OnCall Alerts”
         use_common_alert_schema = false
           }
         }
         arm_role_receiver = {} 
         },
}

Variables.tf:
variable “tfvars” {
default = “”
}

variable “region” {
default = “”
}

Module - Action_Group:
Main.tf:
resource “azurerm_monitor_action_group” “action_groups” {
name = var.action_groups.name
resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
short_name = var.action_groups.short_name

dynamic “email_receiver” {
     for_each = var.action_groups.email_receiver
     content {
              name = email_receiver.value.name
              email_address = email_receiver.value.email_address
              use_common_alert_schema = email_receiver.value.use_common_alert_schema #boolean
             }
     }

dynamic “arm_role_receiver” {
for_each = var.action_groups.arm_role_receiver
     content {
             name = arm_role_receiver.value.name
             role_id = arm_role_receiver.value.role_id
             use_common_alert_schema = 
             arm_role_receiver.value.use_common_alert_schema
             }
}

lifecycle {ignore_changes = [tags]}}

output “action_group_id” {
value = azurerm_monitor_action_group.action_groups.id
}

Variables.tf:
variable “action_groups” {}
variable “resource_group_name” {}

Module - azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert:
Main.tf:
resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert” {

for_each = var.monitor_activity_log_alerts
     name = each.value.name
     resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
     scopes = each.value.scopes
     description = each.value.description

dynamic “criteria” {
for_each = each.value.criteria
     content {
             operation_name = criteria.value.operation_name
             category = criteria.value.category
             dynamic “resource_health” {
             for_each = each.value.resource_health
                content {
                current = resource_health.value.current
                previous = resource_health.value.previous
                reason = resource_health.value.reason
                }
               }
             dynamic “service_health” {
             for_each = each.value.service_health
                content {
                events = service_health.value.events
                locations = service_health.value.locations
                services = service_health.value.services
                }
               }
              }
}

action {action_group_id = var.action_group_ids}

lifecycle {ignore_changes = [tags]}}

Variables.tf:
variable “monitor_activity_log_alerts” {}
variable “action_group_ids” {}

When I try run a terraform plan, I get the following error messages:
Error: Insufficient criteria blocks

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 1, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
1: resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert” {

At least 1 “criteria” blocks are required.

Error: Insufficient criteria blocks

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 1, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
1: resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert” {

At least 1 “criteria” blocks are required.

Error: Insufficient criteria blocks

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 1, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
1: resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert” {

At least 1 “criteria” blocks are required.

Error: Insufficient criteria blocks

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 1, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
1: resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert” {

At least 1 “criteria” blocks are required.

Error: Insufficient criteria blocks

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 1, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
1: resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert” {

At least 1 “criteria” blocks are required.

Error: Insufficient criteria blocks

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 1, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
1: resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert” {

At least 1 “criteria” blocks are required.

Error: Insufficient criteria blocks

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 1, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
1: resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert” {

At least 1 “criteria” blocks are required.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 3, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
3: name = each.value.name
├────────────────
│ each.value is “ApplicationGatewayTotalTime”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 3, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
3: name = each.value.name
├────────────────
│ each.value is tuple with 1 element

This value does not have any attributes.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 3, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
3: name = each.value.name
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “name”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 3, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
3: name = each.value.name
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appgw”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 3, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
3: name = each.value.name
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with 1 attribute “1”

This object does not have an attribute named “name”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 3, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
3: name = each.value.name
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “name”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 3, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
3: name = each.value.name
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appag-totaltime-alert”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 4, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
4: resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
├────────────────
│ each.value is “ApplicationGatewayTotalTime”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 4, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
4: resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
├────────────────
│ each.value is tuple with 1 element

This value does not have any attributes.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 4, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
4: resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “resource_group_name”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 4, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
4: resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appgw”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 4, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
4: resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with 1 attribute “1”

This object does not have an attribute named “resource_group_name”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 4, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
4: resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “resource_group_name”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 4, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
4: resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appag-totaltime-alert”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 5, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
5: scopes = each.value.scopes
├────────────────
│ each.value is “ApplicationGatewayTotalTime”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 5, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
5: scopes = each.value.scopes
├────────────────
│ each.value is tuple with 1 element

This value does not have any attributes.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 5, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
5: scopes = each.value.scopes
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “scopes”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 5, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
5: scopes = each.value.scopes
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appgw”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 5, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
5: scopes = each.value.scopes
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with 1 attribute “1”

This object does not have an attribute named “scopes”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 5, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
5: scopes = each.value.scopes
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “scopes”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 5, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
5: scopes = each.value.scopes
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appag-totaltime-alert”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 6, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
6: description = each.value.description
├────────────────
│ each.value is “ApplicationGatewayTotalTime”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 6, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
6: description = each.value.description
├────────────────
│ each.value is tuple with 1 element

This value does not have any attributes.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 6, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
6: description = each.value.description
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “description”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 6, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
6: description = each.value.description
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appgw”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 6, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
6: description = each.value.description
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with 1 attribute “1”

This object does not have an attribute named “description”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 6, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
6: description = each.value.description
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “description”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 6, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
6: description = each.value.description
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appag-totaltime-alert”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 9, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
9: for_each = each.value.criteria
├────────────────
│ each.value is “ApplicationGatewayTotalTime”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 9, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
9: for_each = each.value.criteria
├────────────────
│ each.value is tuple with 1 element

This value does not have any attributes.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 9, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
9: for_each = each.value.criteria
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “criteria”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 9, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
9: for_each = each.value.criteria
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appgw”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 9, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
9: for_each = each.value.criteria
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with 1 attribute “1”

This object does not have an attribute named “criteria”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 9, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
9: for_each = each.value.criteria
├────────────────
│ each.value is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “criteria”.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on modules\azurerm-monitor-activity-log-alert\main.tf line 9, in resource “azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert” “monitor_activity_log_alert”:
9: for_each = each.value.criteria
├────────────────
│ each.value is “appag-totaltime-alert”

Can’t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

I’ve taken a look at the module.main.tf file and the criteria block is there, and the main.tf says to create them from the module, and the main terraform.tf contains what I think is all the fields for the criteria block - but I’m not any further along in getting past the errors (Or I just can’t see where).
I've tried adding in parts of the criteria block into the main.tf, which then errors out, so I'm sure that the main.tf pulls the module-main.tf for the alerting, and fills the gaps with the terraform.tfvars file - but I can't see where it's failing.
Any advice or pointers would be grateful!

Could you please edit your post and indent the terraform code properly? It's a bit hard to understand it at the moment.

Not sure which part of the code you mean, or what you mean by properly (I seem to get a few different suggestions on how to do it). I've edited it to try make it more readable if that's the issue. Thanks.

Thanks @theangrytech, it looks a bit better now even though is still not indented properly. BTW you can use the terraform fmt command to automatically format Terraform code: developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/fmt

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

query is inconsistent can you please provide the code correctly @theangrytech
